# eclipse : Missing artifact org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.1.3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hbase

I'm new on hbase, and trying to connect hbase from remote application.

But stuck at begin.

I added maven dependency on eclipse(Luna, JavaEE) however eclipse alerts a error
 `Missing artifact org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.1.3`

How can I fix this?

here is dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.CR3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kr.co.vcnc.haeinsa</groupId>
            <artifactId>haeinsa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: If you comment the dependecy of `hbase`,  any other alert is shown?

Comment: @josivan nope. Eclipse just alerts on `hbase` dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your dependecy as type pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! The error is gone! So mush thanks again, josivan

Answer (score -4):

You can try download the jar package`org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.1.3`,
 and put it into your local repository.